# Email input › should respond to change event and change the state of the Login Component

Tags: react-redux, jestjs

I'm getting this error running a jest test

I have this component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { userActionsShape } from 'store/actions/user';
import Scss from './scss/index.scss'

export class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      userId: null,
    };
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { userActions } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = this.state;
      userActions.login(password,email);
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <form className="form-signin">
        <h2 className="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <label htmlFor="inputEmail" className="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" onChange={this.handleChange} name="email"/>
        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChange} name="password" required="" />
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  onClick={this.handleClick}>Log In</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginFormComponent.propTypes = {
  userActions: PropTypes.shape(userActionsShape).isRequired,
};
```

I have this jest test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';


import Login from '../src/app/components/auth';



// within the Login components describe function
describe('Email input', () => {
  
    it('should respond to change event and change the state of the Login Component', () => {
     
     const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
     wrapper.find('#inputEmail').simulate('change', {target: {name: 'email', value: 'peter@klaven'}});
     
    expect(wrapper.state('email')).toEqual('peter@klaven');
    })
})
```

but I'm getting an error when running jest test

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> ● Email input › should respond to change event and change the state of the Login Component
>
> Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was `undefined`.

```
  13 |     it('should respond to change event and change the state of the Login Component', () => {
  14 |
> 15 |      const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
  16 |      wrapper.find('#inputEmail').simulate('change', {target: {name: 'email', value: 'peter@klaven'}});
  17 |
  18 |     expect(wrapper.state('email')).toEqual('peter@klaven');
```

anyone can help please

Answer (score 0):

Either change your component file so that the component is the default export :

export **default** class LoginFormComponent

Or change the way you import it into your test to make use of named exports:

import { LoginFormComponent } from ...

Here’s an article that explains the difference a bit more: https://medium.com/@tharakabimal/understand-the-difference-between-default-and-named-imports-and-exports-f57b62b8b157